# PHP 5.2 Equivalent to Late Static Binding (new static)?

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I am trying to make a script that is built for php 5.3 work on a php 5.2 server. The script uses a lot of late static binding like:

```
return new static($options);
```

What is the equivalent to this in php 5.2? would it be new self somehow? Or is it not possible to achieve the same effect...

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is a related question [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Juts trying to wrap my head around this late static binding stuff...

Comment: There's no equivalent I'm afraid, late static binding was only introduced in PHP 5.3.

Comment: This looks like singletonitis :X

Comment: Like @Robin said, there is no equivalent. Maybe get_class() can help you to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score -1):

I think the only way is to pass by a protected static method that build your singleton and a public static method that defines the class to use.
You can "emulate" it by using the [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function over $this

```
class ParentClass{
    protected static function getInstance2($className){
         //some stuffs here
         return new $className();
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        return self::getInstance2(get_class(self));
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public static function getInstance(){
        return self::getInstance2(get_class(self));
    }
}
```