# New self vs. new static

Tags: php, static, late-static-binding

I am converting a PHP 5.3 library to work on PHP 5.2. The main thing standing in my way is the use of late static binding like `return new static($options);` , if I convert this to `return new self($options)` will I get the same results?

What is the difference between `new self` and `new static`?

Answer (score 1048, accepted):

> will I get the same results?

Not really. I don't know of a workaround for PHP 5.2, though.

> What is the difference between `new self` and `new static`?

`self` refers to the same class in which the `new` keyword is actually written.

`static`, in PHP 5.3's late static bindings, refers to whatever class in the hierarchy you called the method on.

In the following example, `B` inherits both methods from `A`. The `self` invocation is bound to `A` because it's defined in `A`'s implementation of the first method, whereas `static` is bound to the called class (also see [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)).

```
class A {
    public static function get_self() {
        return new self();
    }

    public static function get_static() {
        return new static();
    }
}

class B extends A {}

echo get_class(B::get_self());  // A
echo get_class(B::get_static()); // B
echo get_class(A::get_self()); // A
echo get_class(A::get_static()); // A
```

Comment: You don't have to "pass" the class name, you can always do `get_called_class()`, which is effectively the same as `__CLASS__`, but LSB compatible.

Comment: get_called_class does not exist in <PHP5.3. Hence if you want to get the class name of the instantiated object in PHP5.2 This function does not help when trying to convert a library from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.2

Comment: The function called as self::theFunction() behaves like "I will execute in the context of the class whom I physically belong to." and the function called as static::theFunction() behaves like "I will execute in the context of the class which has been actually called by the outside world". ( Assuming the inheritance scenario ). Thanks

Comment: In my head, I just take whatever is intuitive, and make it opposite. You would think based on the naming, `self` would return itself, and `static` would return something that cannot be overridden... But lo and behold it's the opposite. I never cease to be impressed by PHP's naming, conventions, and overall style. -_-

Answer (score 26):

If the method of this code is not static, you can get a work-around in 5.2 by using `get_class($this)`.

```
class A {
    public function create1() {
        $class = get_class($this);
        return new $class();
    }
    public function create2() {
        return new static();
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

$b = new B();
var_dump(get_class($b->create1()), get_class($b->create2()));
```

The results:

```
string(1) "B"
string(1) "B"
```

Comment: If the method isn't static then late static bindings become totally irrelevant.

Comment: For example, you could use it in "copy" method, where object is copied without using `clone`, but just by re-creating and setting the properties. `$copy = new static(); $copy->set($this->get()); return $copy;`

Comment: @BoltClock Surely not? If you're calling an overridden static method from within an instance method of a subclass, then your choice of `self::` or `static::` is going to affect whether the base class's or subclass's version of that static method is used. In the absence of some reason to think that such a situation occurring inherently indicates bad practice (and I don't see any reason why this should be so), the choice between `self::` and `static::` is just as relevant within non-static methods as it is in static methods. Have I misunderstood your comment, or is one us simply wrong?

Comment: @Mark Amery: Hmm I didn't think of that. You're absolutely right. I had assumed that no static methods were going to be called in the instance method in question, but based on your example, I can see how that would be a very naïve assumption.

Comment: Late Static Bindings doc => http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 13):

In addition to others' answers :

> static:: will be computed using runtime information.

That means you can't use `static::` in a class property because properties values :

> Must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information.

```
class Foo {
    public $name = static::class;

}

$Foo = new Foo;
echo $Foo->name; // Fatal error
```

Using `self::`

```
class Foo {
    public $name = self::class;

}
$Foo = new Foo;
echo $Foo->name; // Foo
```

> Please note that the Fatal error comment in the code i made doesn't indicate where the error happened, the error happened earlier before the object was instantiated as @Grapestain mentioned in the comments

Comment: Note the error is thrown on line 2 `public $name = static::class;`, not on line 7, as suggested by the example. The error says: "static::class cannot be used for compile-time class name resolution" which indicates the problem is not where you try to access the $name field, but far before, at the compilation of the PHP class. Line 7 (or 6) will not be reached in the first example.

Comment: Right, I did not mean to criticise, just clarified what confused me first in the hope it may help others. Helpful example anyway!