# can we call a static function in other static function in a class

Tags: php, oop

can we call a static function in other static function in a class if yes please help me.I am using this php code.

```
static function getconfig()
{
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query='select * from #__yellowpages_config';
$db->setQuery($query);
$result=$db->loadObject();


$config->city=JRequest::getVar('city',0);
$config->country=JRequest::getVar('c',0);

if($config->city==0)

$config->city=$result->city;

if($config->country==0)

$config->country=$result->country;

return $config;

}
static function getitem()
       {
        //how I call the getconfig function here.
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`self::method()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) if you want to refer to the same class.

Use [`static::method()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) if you want to refer to whatever class in hierarchy which you call the method on.

See also this question: [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197655/603003)

Answer (score 4):

Try using `self::getconfig()` instead.

Comment: +1, `self::staticMethod();` and `self::$staticVar;` work just fine, but AFAIK, `theClass::staticMethod();` should work, too.