# PHP new static($variable)

Tags: php, static

```
 $model = new static($variable);
```

All these are within a method inside a class, I am trying to technically understand what this piece of code does. I ran around in the Google world. But can't find anything that leads me to an answer. Is this just another way of saying.

```
 $model = new static $variable;
```

Also what about this

```
 $model = new static;
```

Does this mean I'm initializing a variable and settings it's value to null but I am just persisting the variable not to lose the value after running the method?

Comment: Read [Late Static Bindings](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Comment: Please have a look at the following link to get idea about new Static(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static

Answer (score 13):

static in this case means the current object scope. It is used in late static binding.

Normally this is going to be the same as using `self`. The place it differs is when you have a object heirarchy where the reference to the scope is defined on a parent but is being called on the child.  self in that case would reference the parents scope whereas static would reference the child's

```
class A{
    function selfFactory(){
        return new self();
    }

    function staticFactory(){
        return new static();
    }
}

class B extends A{
}


$b = new B();

$a1 = $b->selfFactory(); // a1 is an instance of A

$a2 = $b->staticFactory(); // a2 is an instance of B
```

It's easiest to think about self as being the defining scope and static being the current object scope.

Answer (score 4):

`self` is simply a "shortcut name" for the class it occurs in. `static` is its newer [*late static binding*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) cousin, which always refers to the *current* class. I.e. when extending a class, `static` can also refer to the child class if called from the child context.

`new static` just means *make new instance of the current class* and is simply the more dynamic cousin of `new self`.

<sub>And yeah, `static` == more dynamic *is* weird.</sub>

Comment: In my search for more knowledge I recently looked into this late static binding craziness, and I can honestly say, It hurts my brain.

Comment: It's not that terrible, really. It's the same `$this` has always behaved, just for classes instead of objects.

Comment: I think it's because, as you say in the last line, static is actually dynamic, it just throws me right off the scent :)

Comment: I just remember that `static` in this case stands for "late *static* binding", and all is right again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put it in the context of a class where `static` is a reference to the class it is called in. We can *optionally* pass `$variable` as a parameter to the `__construct` function of the instance you are creating.

Like so:

```
class myClass {

    private $variable1;

    public function __construct($variable2) {
        $this->variable1 = $variable2;
    }

    public static function instantiator() {
        $variable3 = 'some parameter';
        $model = new static($variable3); // <-this where it happens.
        return $model;
    }
}
```

Here `static` refers to `myClass` and we pass the variable 'some parameter' as a parameter to the `__construct` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new static()` to instantiate a group of class objects from within the class, and have it work with extensions to the class as well.

```
class myClass {
  $some_value = 'foo';
  public function __construct($id) {
    if($this->validId($id)) {
      $this->load($id); 
    }
  }

  protected function validId($id) {
    // check if id is valid.
    return true; // or false, depending
  }

  protected function load($id) {
    // do a db query and populate the object's properties
  }

  public static function getBy($property, $value) {
    // 1st check to see if $property is a valid property
    // if yes, then query the db for all objects that match
    $matching_objects = array();
    foreach($matching as $id) {
      $matching_objects[] = new static($id); // calls the constructor from the class it is called from, which is useful for inheritance.
    }
    return $matching_objects;
  }
}


myChildClass extends myClass {
  $some_value = 'bar'; // 
}


$child_collection = myChildClass::getBy('color','red'); // gets all red ones

$child_object = $child_collection[0];

print_r($child_object); // you'll see it's an object of myChildClass
```

Answer (score -2):

The keyword new is used to make an object of already defined class

$model = new static($variable);

so here there is an object of model created which is an instance of class static

Comment: I don't think static is class, it's variable scope... is it or am i wrong?