# PHP - Why can't I use private method inside public methods?

Tags: php, oop

Why can't I get access to my "incSessionCount" function inside my "newSession" function?

```
class Session {
    private $_num_session = 0;

    private function incSessionCount() {
        $this->_num_session++;
    }

    public static function newSession($key, $value) {
        if( !isset( $_SESSION[$key] ) ) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            $this->incSessionCount();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I just played around, like making `incSessionCount()` `public` and so on...
And then I thought, that it must be even accessible, when it's set to `private` ...

It's possible, that I missed a useful article, which should have helped me, but finally I ended up asking.

So why doesn't this work?

Comment: How exactly does this code fail?

Comment: Because newSession() is `static`, and you can't access instance properties/methods from a static method

Comment: your public method is static

Comment: okay, thank you, never thought, that it's that simple :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `newSession` is `static`, thus you are not supposed to call *instance methods* from it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're trying to do:

```
Session::newSession($key, $value);
```

*instead of*

```
$session = new Session();
$session->newSession($key, $value);
```

The error is not because you're calling a private method from within a public one, but because you're using `$this` instead of `self`.

`$this` special variable represents the current instance object while `self` represents the class itself.

Comment: Note: most of the time [you want to use `static` over of `self`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static) ^^.

Comment: @moonwave99, I don't agree, most of the time you actually want to use `self` instead of `static` which is designed to solve the late static binding "problems" which itself have specific use cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable error display  and set error reporting level to `E_ALL`, you will see the problem is about using `$this` in a wrong context.

See below theses little modifications to do what you want, and check theses pages about

```
class Session {
    private $_num_session = 0;
    private static $inst = null;

    public static function instance(){
      if (!static::$inst)
        static::$inst = new Session();
      return static::$inst;
    }


    private function incSessionCount() {
        $this->_num_session++;
    }

    public static function newSession($key, $value) {
        if( !isset( $_SESSION[$key] ) ) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            Session::getInstance()->incSessionCount();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can look for design pattern and singleton on internet, and use magic __clone() to forbid more than one instance

I only found the german version of the documentation, I don't know why : http://de.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.patterns.php

**EDIT:** Check this link about design patterns : http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

Remember, that `static` methods are binded with the `class`. Non-static methods are binded with the *instance* (when you do something like `$instance = new MyClass();`). But when you call something on the static context, you don't have to have any *instance*.

It's the same, when you want to call something on instance(`$this`), because in static context doesn't exist any *instance*.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the `public` method is `static` and you are trying to use a method for an instantiated object. In a static method the `$this` variable refers to other static methods and properties only.

Comment: In `static` methods called statically `$this` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Calling `$this` from a static context "may" work in old version of PHP or where the error level is low (ie not using strict) but it is fundamentally wrong.