# PHP: self:: vs parent:: with extends

Tags: php, class, static, parent, self

I'm wondering what is the difference between using self:: and parent:: when a static child class is extending static parent class e.g.

```
class Parent {

    public static function foo() {
       echo 'foo';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public static function func() {
       self::foo();
    }

    public static function func2() {
       parent::foo();
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between func() and func2() and if so then what is it ?

Thank you

Regards

Comment: If you've `overridden` foo() in the Child class, then `self::foo()` calls the child class version while `parent::foo()` calls the original parent version

Comment: +1, should have been answer

Comment: `static::foo()` makes it even more fun :)

Comment: OK, but if Child class has no its own definition of foo() then does that mean that there is no difference between the two calls i.e. self:: and parent:: ?

Comment: If child class has no overridden `foo()` then it executes the parent `foo()` code.... there's a difference in the calls, but not in what is executed. Calling `parent::foo()` will always execute the parent class foo() method, even if the child overrides it; calling self::foo() will execute the foo() override if it exists in self (ie the child), otherwise it will execute the parent foo() if no override exists

Comment: thanks, what is the difference then as the result will be exaclty the same ? I understand the difference between self:: and parent:: but not in the above context :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
                Child has foo()     Parent has foo()
self::foo()        YES                   YES               Child foo() is executed
parent::foo()      YES                   YES               Parent foo() is executed
self::foo()        YES                   NO                Child foo() is executed
parent::foo()      YES                   NO                ERROR
self::foo()        NO                    YES               Parent foo() is executed
parent::foo()      NO                    YES               Parent foo() is executed
self::foo()        NO                    NO                ERROR
parent::foo()      NO                    NO                ERROR
```

If you are looking for the correct cases for their use.  `parent` allows access to the inherited class, whereas `self` is a reference to the class the method running (static or otherwise) belongs to.

A popular use of the `self` keyword is when using the Singleton pattern in PHP, `self` doesn't honour child classes, whereas `static` does [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

`parent` provides the ability to access the inherited class methods, often useful if you need to retain some default functionality.

Comment: Thanks, now let's assume that Child hasn't its own foo() and never will then what's the difference between scenario 5 and 6 in terms of using self:: or parent:: keywords? Is there any or they can be used interchangeably? My question refers to these particular scenarios only. Thanks

Comment: I concede defeat! You've won! If you can make those cast-iron guarantees, and you aren't simply trying to confuse anybody else that looks at your code (including yourself in 6-months time) then there is no difference in what is executed, and you can use them interchangeably if you really, really want to!

Comment: Thanks Mark, to not confuse anybody is there any preferable version for these scenarios? I suppose that parent::foo() is more explanatory. What would be your approach ? Thank you

Comment: The method I would probably take is to make use of late static binding, and to use `static::foo()` unless I specifically wanted to force calling `parent::foo()`.... that allows me to implement a foo() in the child should I wish to do so in the future... and even to extend the child class still further... though a lot of it comes down to specific requirements

Comment: Hi @Mark Baker + 1 - when using static:: with inheritance, php will first look in the initial calling class and if it doesn't find it goes and looks for the parent class? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

self is used to call static function and manipulate static variables, which are class specific not object specific.