# PHP class extends Singleton pattern

Tags: php

class singleton:

```
class Singleton
{
    private static $_myself;

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_myself))
        {
            $obj = __CLASS__;
            self::$_myself = new $obj;
        }
        return self::$_myself;
    }
}
```

my class:

```
 class MyApp extends Singleton
    {
        public function show()
        {
            echo 'show';
        }
    }
    MyApp::getInstance()->show();
```

but not working, this error:
Call to undefined method Singleton::show()
somebody can help me?

Comment: This pattern creates lots of tight coupling, which makes your application harder to evolve, test, and re-use. The singleton pattern is fine (one instance used in lots of places), but this very common static function pattern causes a lot of problems. Please use a dependency injection framework. After looking around a bit, PHP-DI looks nice: http://php-di.org/

Answer (score 3):

Because you're returning a `Singleton` class (as you can see by your error), but should be returning a `MyApp` class. You can do this by using the late static binding method [`get_called_class()`](http://www.php.net/get_called_class) introduced in PHP 5.3:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if(!isset(self::$_myself))
    {
        //__CLASS__ = Singleton | get_called_class() = MyApp
        $obj = get_called_class(); 
        self::$_myself = new $obj;
    }
    return self::$_myself;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`self` returns the actual class instance (`Singleton` in this case), so there is no method `show`. But you could use `static` instead of `self` ([Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)) and change `$_myself` from private to protected so it is accessible in child classes.

```php
class Singleton
{
    protected static $_myself;

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(static::$_myself))
        {
            static::$_myself = new static;
        }
        return static::$_myself;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in

```
$obj = __CLASS__;
self::$_myself = new $obj;
```

You create a new instance of the class `Singleton`, not of the class `MyApp`, so the method is not available.

Now h2ooooooo was faster with his answer than I edited, see his answer regarding what to put instead of `__CLASS__`.