# OOP singleton validation to see it doesn't create more than 1 instance

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I've created Singleton class below but how do I know that only one instance has been created. How do I test it? Also, is there any difference between `self::$instance = new FileProcessor()` and `self::$instance = new static()` or which one should I use?

Thanks

**CLASS**

```
class FileProcessor
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::$instance = new FileProcessor();
            //self::$instance = new static();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

$obj_1 = FileProcessor::get_instance();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($obj_1);

$obj_2 = FileProcessor::get_instance();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($obj_2);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FileProcessor Object
(
)
FileProcessor Object
(
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't be using a singleton pattern to begin with. Instead you *dependency inject* an instance of `FileProcessor` to everything that needs it. That means all the places in your app which need `FileProcessor` don't "get it themselves", rather they *receive it* from a higher authority. Instead of:

```
function foo() {
    $fp = FileProcessor::getInstance();
    ...
}
```

you do:

```
function foo(FileProcessor $fp) {
    ...
}
```

This allows you to instantiate exactly one `FileProcessor` and inject it everywhere it's needed. This gives you full control over its use. You can couple this with a registry/dependency injection container pattern to make managing dependencies easier.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. How do I change my example in order to use your second function?

Comment: All of the code you show deals with instantiating a singleton. You basically delete all that. Then you just leave one `$obj_1 = new FileProcessor;` and pass that `$obj_1` to every function and class that needs it.

Comment: BTW, you may also be interested in this: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: Is it like this then?`class FileProcessor
{
 //Whatever
}

$obj = new FileProcessor;

function foo($obj)
{
 echo '<pre>'; var_dump($obj);
}

foo($obj);`

Comment: Exactly. I'd also add the type hint `FileProcessor $obj` to the `function foo`, as shown in my answer.

Comment: I removed it to see what happens and nothing changed but if you think it is best practice or has advantage then I'll use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the result by using `===` operator. In your case: 
`$obj_1 === $obj_2` will return `true` if both objects refer to the same instance. More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php. And also here is a good explanation of using `new static()` : [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Comment: Thanks for the link to see the differences as well. +1

Answer (score 1):

var_dump function allows you to view the contents of the object.
This code demonstrates that the objects are really the same:

```
<?php
class FileProcessor
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    private $arr = array();

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::$instance = new FileProcessor();
            //self::$instance = new static();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
    $this->arr[$key] = $value;
    }
}

$obj_1 = FileProcessor::get_instance();
$obj_1->set('this-is-key', 'this-is-value');
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($obj_1);

$obj_2 = FileProcessor::get_instance();
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($obj_2);
```