# Right way to instantiate class in PHP

Tags: php, instance, instantiation

I am trying to create a method inside class, that will instantiate class that is currently in. But I would also need that from this method to work correctly in all extended classes. As I have learned from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static), it's not good to use `self` keyword for this task. So obvious choice would be using `static` keyword.

But, I've come across different method that also works.

Example:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    private $arg;

    public function __construct( $arg ){
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }

    public function getArg(){return $this->arg;}
    public function setArg($arg){$this->arg = $arg;}

    public function staticInstance()
    {
        return new static( $this->arg );
    }

    public function thisInstance()
    {
        return new $this( $this->arg );
    }

    public function selfInstance()
    {
        return new self( $this->arg );
    }
}

class ExtendedClass extends SimpleClass
{
}

$c1 = 'SimpleClass';
$c2 = 'ExtendedClass';

$inst1 = new $c1('simple');
$inst2 = new $c2('extended');

$static_instance_1 = $inst1->staticInstance();
$this_instance_1 = $inst1->thisInstance();
$self_instance_1 = $inst1->selfInstance();

$static_instance_2 = $inst2->staticInstance();
$this_instance_2 = $inst2->thisInstance();
$self_instance_2 = $inst2->selfInstance();

echo "SimpleClass Instances\n";
echo get_class($static_instance_1);
echo get_class($this_instance_1);
echo get_class($self_instance_1);

echo "ExtendedClass Instances\n";
echo get_class($static_instance_2);
echo get_class($this_instance_2);
echo get_class($self_instance_2);
```

As I can see from this example, both `staticInstance` and `thisInstance` produce "correct" results. Or do they?

Can someone explain difference between these two methods and which one is "correct" one.

Comment: Not sure, but, as long as you use `new` there is no difference. It's getting interesting when using `clone` and storing the instance in itself.

Comment: My knowledge of static vs self is such that if, from an object instance of an extended class, you were to call a method that it inherited, which, for example, create a `new static ... `, it will create a new instance of the extended class. Had it have used `self`, it will create a new instance of the parent (because the method exists in the parent)

Comment: Everything about static and self dilemma is explained in link that I referenced in first paragraph of my question. My dilemma is between $this and static :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) says:

As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a feature called late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance.

More precisely, late static bindings work by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call". In case of static method calls, this is the class explicitly named (usually the one on the left of the :: operator); in case of non static method calls, it is the class of the object. A "forwarding call" is a static one that is introduced by self::, parent::, static::, or, if going up in the class hierarchy, forward_static_call(). The function get_called_class() can be used to retrieve a string with the name of the called class and static:: introduces its scope.

This feature was named "late static bindings" with an internal perspective in mind. "Late binding" comes from the fact that static:: will not be resolved using the class where the method is defined but it will rather be computed using runtime information. It was also called a "static binding" as it can be used for (but is not limited to) static method calls.

Limitations of self:

Static references to the current class like self:: or **CLASS** are resolved using the class in which the function belongs, as in where it was defined:

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        self::who();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
?>
```

The above example will output: `A`

Late Static Bindings' usage:

Late static bindings tries to solve that limitation by introducing a keyword that references the class that was initially called at runtime. Basically, a keyword that would allow you to reference B from test() in the previous example. It was decided not to introduce a new keyword but rather use static that was already reserved.

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
?>
```

The above example will output: `B`

`$this` keyword refers to current object and you cannot use it in static methods. When you say `return $this` it means that some method returns the same object on which it was invoked.

So the correct way would be using `static` keyword because if you say `return new static()` it refers to the class the method is currently in.

Comment: I like your answer because it resolves another problem that i have with magic constants :D

Comment: Is there a way to get class name without redefining function who? (No extra lines of code in class B)

Comment: You can also use php reflection API for this purpose. Something like this: `$reflB = new ReflectionClass('B'); echo $reflB->name;` So you'll get the class name