# How to get parent class instance?

Tags: php

I have two classes:

Singleton.php

```
namespace Core\Common;

class Singleton
{
    protected static $_instance;

    private function __construct(){}
    private function __clone(){}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Config.php

```
namespace Core;

class Config extends Common\Singleton
{

    private $configStorage = array();    

    public function setConfig($configKey, $configValue)
    {
        $this->configStorage[$configKey] = $configValue;
    }

    public function getConfig($configKey)
    {
        return $this->configStorage[$configKey];
    }   
}
```

my index.php

```
require_once 'common\Singleton.php';
require_once 'Config.php';
$config = \Core\Config::getInstance();
$config->setConfig('host', 'localhost');
```

but got the error: "Call to undefined method Core\Common\Singleton::setConfig()"

So as i can see getInstance() return me Singleton class instance, but not Config, how i can return Config instance from Singleton?

Comment: `getInstance` is a static method in `singleton`. This is instantiating itself, thus there's no instance of Config. Overload `getInstance` in Config and use it from there then

Comment: but i dont want diblicate getInstance code in all singleton classes, really there is no other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `getInstance` to this:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(static::$_instance)) {
        static::$_instance = new static;
    }
    return static::$_instance;
}
```

The difference between `self` and `static` is highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static):

> self refers to the same class whose method the new operation takes place in.
>
> static in PHP 5.3's late static bindings refers to whatever class in the hierarchy which you call the method on.

So it means that is bounded dynamically to the extending class, hence `new static` in your case refers to the `Config` class, using `self` will always statically refers to the `Singleton` class.

Working [example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f70ab0f14163b188e9f069dca6f6073f16338dd).

Comment: It works. Thank you dude) Late static binding, why i dont think about that?

Comment: You're welcome, it was a surprise for me too the first time I used it.