# PHP static keyword used with new in building an object

Tags: php, oop, static

I am reading about Patterns in OOP and came across this code for the singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton
{
    /**
     * @var Singleton reference to singleton instance
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * gets the instance via lazy initialization (created on first usage)
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {

        if (null === static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * is not allowed to call from outside: private!
     *
     */
    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * prevent the instance from being cloned
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __clone()
    {

    }

    /**
     * prevent from being unserialized
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __wakeup()
    {

    }
}
```

The part in question is `static::$instance = new static;`. What exactly does `new static` do or how does this example work. I am familiar with your average `new Object` but not `new static`. Any references to php documentation would help greatly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically that is a extendable class, and whenever you call `getInstance()` you will get a singleton of the whatever class you call it in (that extends this singleton class). If you only use it in one instance, you could hardcode the classname, or use `new self` if you had hardcoded this in your class.

Also, the singleton is regarded a **anti-pattern**, see the answer her for more details on this pattern [why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the answer in the context of the singleton.