# Meaning of code in Laravel artisan initialization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I decided to look on how artisan is initialized in Laravel 4.2 and saw function make($app)

```
public static function make($app)
    {
    $app->boot();

    $console = with($console = new static('Laravel Framework', $app::VERSION))
                            ->setLaravel($app)
                            ->setExceptionHandler($app['exception'])
                            ->setAutoExit(false);

    $app->instance('artisan', $console);

    return $console;
}
```

I am not really newbie in PHP but not master either... And I cannot understand wholly the meaning of (from PHP point of view)

```
$console = with($console = new static('Laravel Framework', $app::VERSION))
                        ->setLaravel($app)
                        ->setExceptionHandler($app['exception'])
                        ->setAutoExit(false);
```

Here is the link to source
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php

Comment: Where did you find this code. A link to source would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` method is a helper method ([Laravel helper methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers)) which allows you to method chain. Es specially in PHP 5.3.X environment

From the documentation

```
$value = with(new Foo)->doWork();
```

This would create a new instance off the class Foo and call the method do on Foo

From the source

```
if ( ! function_exists('with'))
{
    /**
     * Return the given object. Useful for chaining.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $object
     * @return mixed
     */
    function with($object)
    {
        return $object;
    }
}
```

When you provide it an instance of an object -> it will return this instance. Now you are able to call methods or properties on this object.

this would be the same as doing the following:

```
 $foo = new Foo();
 $value = $foo->doWork();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code comments it:

> Create a new Console application.

I imagine your asking more about how.

1. It calls the class constructor to create a new instance. Review the [symfony class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php#L83) for more details on the constructor.
2. Using [`with()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#miscellaneous) allows chaining calls the additional methods `setLaravel()`, `setExceptionHandler()`, etc which finalize setting up the Laravel Application instance.

To learn more about `new static` review this question: [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static).