# Extend class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, parsedown

I am trying to extend a class:

```
class CustomParsedown extends Parsedown {
    protected function blockComment($Line) { return; }
    protected function blockCommentContinue($Line, array $Block) { return; }
    protected function blockHeader($Line) { return; }
    protected function blockSetextHeader($Line, array $Block = NULL) { return; }
}

function markdown($markdown) {
    return CustomParsedown::instance()->setMarkupEscaped(true)->text($markdown);
}
```

If I run `markdown()` with markdown from another page, the changes in the code do not go into effect. For example, I can still create a heading. Am I extending the class correctly?

Comment: What version is your PHP by the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Parsedowns `static function instance()` is referencing `$instance = new self();` which means it will instantiate a new `Parsedown` class and not your extending class.

Try duplicating their instance method into your class, I've also changed `new self` into `new static`.

```
class CustomParsedown extends Parsedown {
  static function instance($name = 'default')
  {
      if (isset(self::$instances[$name]))
      {
          return self::$instances[$name];
      }
      $instance = new static();
      self::$instances[$name] = $instance;
      return $instance;
  }
  private static $instances = array();
}
```

https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php

---

See also [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Comment: After amending the code, I get `Cannot access property CustomParsedown::$instances `

Comment: ok add `private static $instances = array();` as well to your class

Comment: Huh, now I get `Undefined index: name ` on [line 1384](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php#L1384). Nevermind, that's a bug in my code.

Comment: It's quite strange because now that I look a their documentation, you've done exactly what they documented yet it didn't work... https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/wiki/Tutorial:-Create-Extensions

Comment: Exactly. I was confused as well, especially because there did not seem to be any github issues related to this exact problem.

Comment: Time to create one :)

Comment: Go ahead :D Creating an issue (and fix?) will surely help future users.