# How the static property extend from parent?

Tags: php

The code is here:

```
class A {
    public static $property = 1;

    public function test(){
       echo self::$property;
   }
}

class B extends A{
    public static $property = 2;
}
$b = new B();

echo $b->test() . "\n";
```

Console log:

```
$:1
```

I know that the class `B` has overwrite the static property.

What is the cause of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have added

```
`echo self::$property;`
```

to `test()` of `A` whether you overwrite the value of static variable in extended class or not it will refer to the parent class value but when your change this to

```
`echo static::$property;`
```

it will give the value based on the class object.[more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Try this:
[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/330607dae2c1aef1285efc994892eb0c68f65623)

Answer (score 0):

> - self is the same as $this for static methods/variables but always acts on the defining class.
> - static is the same as $this for static methods/varialbes but always acts on the calling class (this is known as late static binding which is a relatively new feature of php

Source: [Read article](http://www.efrag.gr/2012/12/php-self-vs-static/)

If you want to echo the value from the class you made the object of, you can use use the below,

```
class A {
    public static $property = 1;

    public function test(){
       echo static::$property; // changed self to static
    }
}
```

Hope you understood! Thanks.

Comment: I understand it now.Thanks a lot.