# Creating a new instance of an inherited class through the inherited static methods

Tags: php, inheritance

I've got a method in my class to create a new 'self' on execution.

```
class foo {
    private $id;

    public function __construct( $id ) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public static function byId( $id ) {
        return new self( $id );
    }  

}
```

And now i want to use the byId method from foo and use it in bar, by doing as such

```
class bar extends foo {
    public function test() {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

now I should be able to do bar::byId( id ), however this will always return the parent object and not the bar object.
 **How can  i make sure that byId will return the object of the inherited class if it's called through it?**

Comment: How would `test()` ever call `foo::byId()`? What..

Comment: Lawrence Cherone I am unsure what you mean, i want to be able to call bar->test() by using the static bar::byId( id ) where the byId static method is inherited from foo

Comment: Have you tried using `return new static($id);` isntead of `return new self($id);` ?

Comment: Oh right, yeah @PhilippMaurer has sorted it ;p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Thank you, i never knew about new static, as such i did not try looking for this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return new static($id);` instead of `return new self($id);`