# How to get parent namespace from Trait

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I created a trait and i want to be able to get the namespace of the class using the trait. is this possible? `self::class` gives me the class name of the parent but not the entire namespace

Comment: Did you try `__NAMESPACE__`? https://3v4l.org/oRqvK

Comment: Have you tried `static::class`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static/5197655

Comment: Not reproducible: https://3v4l.org/NQQEk

Comment: @LawrenceCherone actually that won't work, that'll return the namespace of the trait, not the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ReflectionClass->getNamespaceName() with the reflection of self::class.

MyTrait.php

```
namespace MyTraitNamespace;

Trait MyTrait{
    public function echoClassNamespace()
    {
        $ref = new \ReflectionClass(self::class);
        echo $ref->getNamespaceName(); //Will echo MyClassNamespace
    }

    public function echoTraitNamespace()
    {
        echo __NAMESPACE__; //Will echo MyTraitNamespace
    }
}
```

MyClass.php

```
namespace MyClassNamespace;

use MyTraitNamespace\MyTrait;

class MyClass{
    use MyTrait;
}
```