# PHP abstract class access of constant below

Tags: php, class, static, abstract, factorization

Is it possible in PHP, that an abstract class accesses a constant of the class below?

For example, can I factorize getName in Generic ?

```
abstract class Generic {
    abstract public function getName(): string;
}

class MorePreciseA extends Generic {
    private const NAME = "More Precise A";

    public function getName(): string {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}

class MorePreciseB extends Generic {
    private const NAME = "More Precise B";

    public function getName(): string {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter it's abstract, there is no way for a parent class to know anything about a property of a child class (even if it wasn't private). Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe we can suggest a different design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the difference between `self::` and `static::` comes in. More on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197655/7528944).

```
abstract class Generic {
    protected const NAME = "Generic";

    public function getName(): string {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}

class MorePreciseA extends Generic {
    protected const NAME = "More Precise A";
}

class MorePreciseB extends Generic {
    protected const NAME = "More Precise B";

}


$a = new MorePreciseA();
$b = new MorePreciseB();

var_dump($a->getName(), $b->getName());
```

Will result in

```
// string(7) "Generic"
// string(7) "Generic"
```

But if you replace the `Generic` implementation like so

```
abstract class Generic {
    public function getName(): string {
        return static::NAME;
    }
}
```

Then it will output

```
// string(14) "More Precise A"
// string(14) "More Precise B"
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !